# Binding DataGridView to a reflected object array

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection, datagridview

I'm trying to bind a DataGridView to a reflected object array. The header columns bind fine, the correct name is displayed and seven rows are displayed, the issue is the rows are empty.
[image: Example from the program]
When I check the databound items it looks fine.
[image: Databound items]
It shows that it's the correct reflected model and the values.

This is the snippet I've got so far.

```
private void comboBoxTables_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var type = (Type)(this.comboBoxTables.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem).Value;
    object[] result = this.DataLoader.Get(type);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = result;
    this.dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();

    var properties = type.GetProperties();
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(property.Name, property.Name);
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[property.Name].DataPropertyName = property.Name;
    }

    this.dataGridView1.Refresh();
}
```

This snippet:

```
object[] result = this.DataLoader.Get(type);
```

Fetches the data from a dictionary containing the reflected values as an object array.

I've tried using a binding source instead and some other ugly hacks, but I can't get the rows to display any data.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

**SOLVED**

Not sure why this solved the issue, but by adding a `ToList()` on the result, the data was displayed correctly. It might be because of an un-enumerated IEnumerable earlier in the code.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = result.ToList();
```

[image: Expected result]

Comment: Apparently, your `DataLoader.Get()` returns *almost* empty handed; records without value (empty or null). But, is this a good design? Do you need to resort to reflection? What objects are these? Can't they have a common Interface. Can't you use a generic `DataLoader.Get<T>((...));`?

Comment: The records aren't empty, please read the updated question. There is a `Get<T>` method, but it's not possible to use it in this particular scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Not sure why this solved the issue, but by adding a `ToList()` on the result, the data was displayed correctly. I'll fill in the blanks once I know why this is the case.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = result.ToList();
```

[image: Expected result]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate your code and the real problem, in my opinion, is the

```
var properties = type.GetProperties();
```

not being a Property, ironically. Meaning they don't have "get{}, set{}" as normal properties.

My solution is to make an external class to work as a "shell" for the properties you get from your reflection:

```
public class Shell
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Shell(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

and something along these lines:

```
    var type = (Type)(this.comboBoxTables.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem).Value;
    object[] result = this.DataLoader.Get(type);

    //this.dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();

    var properties = type.GetProperties();

    List<Shell> shells = new List<Shell>();
    foreach (var item in properties)
    {
        shells.Add(new Shell(item.Name));
    }

    dataGridView1.DataSource = shells;

    foreach (var property in shells)
    {
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(property.Name, property.Name);
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[property.Name].DataPropertyName = property.Name;
    }

    this.dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

Edit: Forgot to change datagrid datasource to the newly created list of shells

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your solution would solve the issue - but I managed to resolve the issue by enumerating it to a `List<object>`. Please read the updated question.